# unknown bitmap configuration ,app crashes on starting

Tags: java, android, bitmap

The resId does not return 0 but the app crashes and log says

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown bitmap configuration

when I create bitmap background.

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    static int mheight, mwidth = 0;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
    ListView updates = view.findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    //older updates to be shown here
    ArrayList<String> fetcheddata = new ArrayList<>();
    fetcheddata.add(0, "sample data");
    fetcheddata.add(1, "sample data");
    fetcheddata.add(2, "sample data");

    //main image is id for imageview in xml
    ImageView main_image = view.findViewById(R.id.mainimage);
    //getting height and width of imageview , having no android:src 0dp
    mheight = main_image.getMaxHeight();
    mwidth = main_image.getMaxWidth();
    //getting big values in log
    Log.v("NNNNNNNNN", "" + mwidth + "," + mheight);
    // main_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.do_dont);


    String imageName = "picture";
    //getting resource id
    int resID = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("@drawable/do_dont", "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
    Log.v("resource id ", "" + resID);
    ImageView image = view.findViewById(R.id.mainimage);
    image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    image.setImageResource(resID);
    image.buildDrawingCache();
    Bitmap bmap = image.getDrawingCache();

    Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) mheight, (int) mwidth, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    //getting image properites (image contained in drawable )
    float originalWidth = image.getWidth();
    float originalHeight = image.getHeight();

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);

    float scale = mwidth / originalWidth;

    float xTranslation = 0.0f;
    float yTranslation = (mheight - originalHeight * scale) / 2.0f;

    Matrix transformation = new Matrix();
    transformation.postTranslate(xTranslation, yTranslation);
    transformation.preScale(scale, scale);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmap, transformation, paint);
    main_image.setImageBitmap(background);
    main_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.mainfragment_listview, fetcheddata);
    updates.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: what is your mHEight and mWidth value ?

Comment: V/NNNNNNNNN: 2147483647,2147483647

Comment: thats my log message

Comment: these are very large values so based on this values it is saying configs are invalid.. for now try putting test values like 2000, 2000 for now and see what happens..

Comment: Thanks Aalap ,  now it says that the when i im refrencing null object when i create bmap = image.getDrawingCache